# Is there a ZKTeco community?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Recently, I downloaded the latest `ZKFinger SDK-v5.3.0.21-Lite` from the [manufacture's website](https://www.zkteco.com/product/ZKFinger_SDK_5.3_Lite_568.html) and have been testing it. It finally offered a Java SDK. I will also be doing some testing with `ZKTeco K-14`. The trouble is, most of the documentation looks like this:

```
public static int SetParameters(long devHandle, int code, byte[] paramValue, int size) 

This function is used to set a parameter.
```

I moved the demo from Swing to JavaFX, to make it more readable from an MVC perspective, yet I don't understand how it is connecting or finding devices;  there wasn't anything related to IP addresses, ports, or network configuration. Has anyone tried this before? What I am looking for is the ability to manipulate the device without the manufacture's software (the manufacture's software is a mess, and the documentation is poor).

In my research, I found the terms: `Reverse Engineering`, `Proxygen`, `JNI`, `DLL`, `DLL to JAR`, and similar. No one seems to know anything about this topic. Where can I ask for help?

Comment: Could be SO, but this question says you haven't done much research yet. That's a valid reason for a downvote. It also suggests that the question is essentially asking for links, or a tutorial, both of which are off topic. You really should start at the source and learn more about it. If nothing, it will help you craft a narrow, answerable question.